# How to order by a related model in default scope? -- Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

**How can I write the following default scope:**

```
class SimilarMerchant < ActiveRecord::Base

  # relationships
  belongs_to :merchant
  belongs_to :similar_merchant, :foreign_key => 'similar_merchant_id', :class_name => "Merchant"

  # scopes
  default_scope order('merchants.is_paid DESC').order('score DESC')

end
```

Basically I want to sort by a `merchant.is_paid` field (which belongs to a related model)

**Any advice?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
default_scope joins(:merchant).order('merchants.is_paid DESC, score DESC')
```

**And please bear in mind it can be slow, depending on the number of the records**

Comment: But please bear in mind it can be slow, depending on the number of the records

Comment: Any order by statement can be slow. It's like saying that this car can go backwards :-) Anyway, works fine, thanks!

Comment: I'm getting 'PG::Error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry`

Answer (score 6):

here's what you could do to have required functionality but it's not great idea to do so, please read until the end

you can define your default scope to also include merchants association and then order by `merchants.is_paid DESC, score DESC`

would look something like

```
default_scope includes(:merchants).order('merchants.is_paid DESC, score DESC')
```

however that means every time you grab similar merchant objects for any reason you will have association loaded as well

this is not great and i would suggest to have a explicit scope for loading similar merchants with association and ordering:

```
scope :with_merchants, includes(:merchants).order(...)
```

that way you always know in your code what exactly is being loaded from database

Answer (score 2):

So, do you want all the queries from `SimilarMerchant` model to be ordered by a column in the `merchants`? I doubt your requirement, but if it is so you will have to join `merchants` table also in the default scope

```
default_scope joins(:merchant).order('merchants.is_paid DESC, similar_merchants.score DESC')
```

It will be better if you define this as a separate scope and call this scope when you need it like this. Also, you need to decide whether you need the relation `merchant` or `similar_merchant`. If you want `similar_merchant`, you will have to do `joins(:similar_merchant)`.

Note that :merchant is singular. i.e. you have to specify the relationship name specified in model (as in `belongs_to :merchant`).