# Rails - Sort by join table data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, has-many-through

I've got a RoR project in the works. Here are the applicable sections of my models.

**Home**

```
has_many :communities, :through => :availabilities
has_many :availabilities, :order => "price ASC"
```

**Community**

```
has_many :homes, :through => :availabilities
has_many :availabilities
```

**Availability**

```
belongs_to :home
belongs_to :community
```

*The "availabilities" table in the database has the additional data column "price"*

So now I can call

```
@home.availabilities.each do |a|
  a.community.name
  a.price
```

and get back the availabilities data ordered by price as I want. My question is this:

Is there a way to automatically order Homes by `avaliabilities.first.price` (first = lowest)? Maybe something with `default_scope :order`?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I would suggest to avoid using `default_scope`, especially on something like price on another table.  Every time you'll use that table, join and ordering will take place, possibly giving strange results in complex queries and anyway making your query slower.

There's nothing wrong with a scope of its own, it's simpler and it's even clearer, you can make it as simple as:

```
scope :ordered, -> { includes(:availabilities).order('availabilities.price') }
```

I would call it `price_ordered`.

PS: Remember to add an index on `price`; Also see other great answers in here to decide between **join/include**.

Comment: Do you need to use `includes` instead of joins?

Comment: Depends, @TeWu is doing a great job at explaining the difference in his answer. In particular the link to Tom Dallimore's blog is awesome.

Comment: @ecoologic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56669484/how-to-get-value-using-join-table-with-different-values

Answer (score 23):

Figured it out with help from [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471751/how-to-order-by-a-related-model-in-default-scope-rails-3-1).

I moved the ordering out of the Home model and into the Availability model:

**Availability**

```
default_scope :order => "price ASC"
```

Then I eager loaded availabilities into the Home model and sorted by price:

**Home**

```
default_scope :include => :availabilities, :order => "availabilities.price ASC"
```

Answer (score 16):

@ecoologic [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34112277/6231376):

```
scope :ordered, -> { includes(:availabilities).order('availabilities.price') }
```

is great, but it should be mentioned that `includes` could, and in some cases should be replaced by `joins`. They both have their optimal use cases (see: [#1](https://web.archive.org/web/20160630204753/http://tomdallimore.com/blog/includes-vs-joins-in-rails-when-and-where/), [#2](https://scoutapm.com/blog/activerecord-includes-vs-joins-vs-preload-vs-eager_load-when-and-where)).

From practical standpoint there are two main differences:

1. `includes` loads associated record(s); in this case `Availability` records. `joins` don't load any associated record(s). So you should use `includes` when you want to use data from join model e.g. display `price` somewhere. On the other hand, `joins` should be used if you intend to use join model's data only in query e.g. in `ORDER BY` or `WHERE` clauses.
2. `includes` loads all records, while `joins` loads only those records that have associated join model. So in OP's case, `Home.includes(:availabilities)` would load all homes, while `Home.joins(:availabilities)` would load only those homes that have associated at least one availability.

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208636/rails-include-vs-joins).

Comment: That optimal use cases link is now broken

Comment: Thanks for info. The link is broken because the linked blog is dead ... what a shame. I've linked to archived version of this blog post, and also added a link to some not prehistoric blog post on this subject ;)

Answer (score 11):

Another way to achieve this:

```
scope :ordered, -> { includes(:availabilities).order(Availability.arel_table[:price]) }
```

You can also specify  `ASC`   direction with

```
scope :ordered, -> { includes(:availabilities).order(Availability.arel_table[:price].asc) }
```

`DESC`:

```
scope :ordered, -> { includes(:availabilities).order(Availability.arel_table[:price].desc) }
```

Using `arel_table` on `ActiveRecord` model makes you save against scenario when table name changed (but it happens very rarely).

Note that it is nice to add `main_table#id` for determinate sorting.

So final version would be:

```
scope :ordered, -> {
  includes(:availabilities).
    order(Availability.arel_table[:price].asc, order(Home.arel_table[:id].asc)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In Rails 5.2+, you might get a deprecation warning when passing a string param to order method:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Dangerous query method (method whose arguments are used as raw SQL) called with non-attribute argument(s): "table.column". Non-attribute arguments will be disallowed in Rails 6.0. This method should not be called with user-provided values, such as request parameters or model attributes.

To solve this, you can use `Arel.sql()`:

```
scope :ordered, -> {
  includes(:availabilities).order(Arel.sql('availabilities.price'))
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also sort linked tables like this (e.g.):

```
class User
  has_many :posts
end

class Post
  belongs_to :user

  scope :sorted_by_user_and_title, -> { 
    joins(:user).merge(
     User.order(first_name: :asc, last_name: :asc)
    )
    .order(title: :desc)
    # SELECT * FROM `posts`
    # INNER JOIN `users` ON `posts`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
    # ORDER BY
    # `users`.`first_name` ASC, `users`.`last_name` ASC, `posts`.`title` DESC;
  }
  scope :sorted_by_title_and_user, -> { 
    order(title: :desc)
    .joins(:user).merge(
     User.order(first_name: :asc, last_name: :asc)
    )
    # SELECT * FROM `posts`
    # INNER JOIN `users` ON `posts`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
    # ORDER BY
    # `posts`.`title` DESC, `users`.`first_name` ASC, `users`.`last_name` ASC;
  }
end
```

Regards