# Sorting by joined table value with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to sort a list of items based on the value of field on a joined table. Here's what I've got so far:

```
FeaturedEvent.joins(:event).order('event.start_datetime').limit(5)
```

This looks right to me but when it's run it returns a Postgres error about there being a missing FROM statement:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "event" LINE 1: ...ts"."id" = "featured_events"."event_id" ORDER BY event.star... ^ : SELECT "featured_events".* FROM "featured_events" INNER JOIN "events" ON "events"."id" = "featured_events"."event_id" ORDER BY event.start_datetime LIMIT 5
```

I tried the suggestions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197649/rails-sort-by-join-table-data) about putting the ordering in default scope but it came out with the same error – I'm guessing it's a Postgres thing.

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
FeaturedEvent.includes(:event).order('events.start_datetime').limit(5)
```

In your order the table name should be the real database table name.

As I guess, the table name must be `events`

Comment: @krishna sahoo : Shouldn't **include** be **includes**? Can you look at this [link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html) and when I am using **references** in (postgres db) method then I am getting undefined method `references ActiveRecord::Relation` for the query 'asdsdfsdf'

Comment: @krishna sahoo : Shouldn't **include** be **includes**? Can you look at this [link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html) and when I am using **references** in (postgres db) method then I am getting undefined method `references ActiveRecord::Relation` for the query  `@messages = Message.includes(:sender).where("UPPER(body) like UPPER(?) or UPPER(body) like UPPER(?) or UPPER(sender.first_name) like UPPER(?)", "%#{"sus"}%", "%#{"ang"}%", "%#{"bar"}%").references(:people)`.

Comment: @zeal, Yes it should be `includes`

Answer (score 1):

Your table name is events so you just have to add s in event

```
FeaturedEvent.joins(:event).order('events.start_datetime').limit(5)
```