# ActiveRecord order by a specific relations's value

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bar
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
end
```

I'd like to order my :foos... based on its last :bar

So, let's say:

```
Foo.first.bars => [{key: 'a', value: 1}, {key: 'b', value: 2}, {key: 'c', value: 3}]
```

So... `Foo.first.bars.last.value => 3`

I have a bunch of :foos, each having a bunch of :bars, but I only care about the last :bar.

Can I sort my :foos based on its last :bars `value`? Would Bar need a scope?

For instance...

```
Foo.includes(:bars).order('bars.last.value')
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have a table of :foos. I want to be able to sort them based on the value of each :foo's last :bar. I'm positive a scope will work somewhere, but I haven't figured it out yet. I can achieve what I'm after by using enumerable... `Foo.all.sort_by(&:some_method)` where `some_method` is calculating the last :bar's `value`. Does that clear it up?

Comment: my problem is, enumerable is slow...

Comment: does something like this help --  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197649/rails-sort-by-join-table-data

Answer (score 1):

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bar
  scope :latest_foo_value, ->(ord) { includes(:foos).order("foos.value #{ord.upcase}") }
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
  default_scope order: 'created_at DESC'
end
```

Thanks, @Doon! If you wanna copy and paste this into your own answer, I'll gladly give you credit. Do you know if there's a way to call a named scope on Bar? Something like:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bar
  scope :latest_foo_value, ->(ord) { includes(:foos).order("foos.current.value #{ord.upcase}") }
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
  scope :current, -> { order('created_at DESC') }
end
```

That doesn't work... `Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'foos.current.value' in 'order clause'`.

Cheers!